# Trouble in starting my jetty server on a remote server

Tags: java, jetty

I have started a jetty server in my remote server. But I got problem accessing the default page. I followed the getting started steps and used the command `java -jar start.jar` to start the server. The port is set to `8080`. When I use my Ip http://20.14.228.123:8080/ The site is never found. Do you guys have any clue of what I have done wrong? According to my terminal window it is running.

**UPDATE:**

sorry I ran wget localhost:8080 and connection failed it says. But I can go in to the default page though. I'm newbie in Java apps deployment, but I exported a war file on my computer and placed it under webapps in the jetty folder is that right procedure? because it don't runs. According to my web.xml in my webapp a servlet is mapped through /Push/GetContacts and when I enter the destination(http://localhost:8080/Push/GetContacts) in my web browser it don't show up?

**FINAL:**

Never mind I fixed it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try to run **wget localhost:8080** from you server terminal? Just to check that port\ip not blocked somewhere on network layer? It must download html showed by jetty if it actually run...

Comment: I know what I did wrong. I'm using an ec2 instance. And you have to enable the port first in AWS Management

Comment: sorry I ran `wget localhost:8080` and connection failed it says. But I can go in to the default page though. I'm newbie in Java apps deployment, but I exported a war file on my computer and placed it under webapps in the jetty folder is that right procedure? because it don't runs. According to my web.xml in my webapp a servlet is mapped through /Push/GetContacts and when I enter the destination(`http://localhost:8080/Push/GetContacts`) in my web browser it don't show up?

Comment: it's hard to say something from distance ) - maybe you can check this one -http://www.enavigo.com/2008/08/29/deploying-a-web-application-to-jetty/

Comment: check is it all right with **contextPath**  and **war** in you case - it can be it... (and not forget about putting context file into **$JETTY_HOME/contexts**

Comment: Hi guys! I already fixed that problem now. But thanks for your support, but I got a small problem left: how do I get the jetty server to not shut down all the time after I close down the terminal?

Comment: try **nohup java -jar start.jar &**

Answer (score 0):

Q: how do I get the jetty server to not shut down all the time after I close down the terminal?
A: start Jetty as service(process)